# Rotate a vector by 90 degree via cross product

Tags: matlab, rotation, linear-algebra, geometry-surface, cross-product

I am trying to understand a code wherein the authors have rotated vectors in 3D by 90 degrees. They used a cross-product to do so. How cross-product can incorporate rotation by 90 degrees? Any explanation would be helpful.

```
    % Inputs:
    %   V  #vertices by dim list of mesh vertex positions
    %   F  #faces by simplex-size list of mesh face indices
    % Gradient of a scalar function defined on piecewise linear elements (mesh)
    % is constant on each triangle i,j,k:
    % grad(Xijk) = (Xj-Xi) * (Vi - Vk)^R90 / 2A + (Xk-Xi) * (Vj - Vi)^R90 / 2A
    % grad(Xijk) = Xj * (Vi - Vk)^R90 / 2A + Xk * (Vj - Vi)^R90 / 2A + 
    %             -Xi * (Vi - Vk)^R90 / 2A - Xi * (Vj - Vi)^R90 / 2A
    % where Xi is the scalar value at vertex i, Vi is the 3D position of vertex
    % i, and A is the area of triangle (i,j,k). ^R90 represent a rotation of 
    % 90 degrees
    %
    % renaming indices of vertices of triangles for convenience
    i1 = F(:,1); i2 = F(:,2); i3 = F(:,3); 
    % #F x 3 matrices of triangle edge vectors, named after opposite vertices
    v32 = V(i3,:) - V(i2,:);  v13 = V(i1,:) - V(i3,:); v21 = V(i2,:) - V(i1,:);

    % area of parallelogram is twice area of triangle
    % area of parallelogram is || v1 x v2 || 
    n  = cross(v32,v13,2); 

    % This does correct l2 norm of rows so that it contains #F list of twice
    % triangle areas
    dblA = normrow(n);

    % now normalize normals to get unit normals
    u = normalizerow(n);

    % rotate each vector 90 degrees around normal ---- ????
    eperp21 = bsxfun(@times,cross(u,v21),1./dblA);
    eperp13 = bsxfun(@times,cross(u,v13),1./dblA);
```

Comment: If you could show the code it would be easier for us to try to help you

Comment: @Thales have shown the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 3d the [*cross product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) `a x b` of two vectors `a` and `b` results in a vector `p := a x b` that is *perpendicular* to both `a` and `b`.

This means if you cross-multiply a vector with an unit vector `u` that represents the rotation axis, you will get a vector that is rotated 90 degrees around the rotation axis.

Comment: Can u please elaborate on "This means if you cross-multiply a vector with an unit vector u that represents the rotation axis, you will get a vector that is rotated 90 degrees around the rotation axis". Like how is it true ?

Comment: @M.B. Sounds like a question for https://math.stackexchange.com/, you have been shown how to program it, which is the purpose of this site.

Comment: @M.B. Yes math.SE would be better suited for mathematical questions. To come back to your comment: Can you maybe explain first what properties of the cross product you already know? Depending on your perspective this is almost true by *definition* of the CP, so that is why I'm asking.

Comment: @M.B. Consider two vectors in 3D drawn with their origin at the same point. They necessarily lie on some plane as long as they aren't parallel. The cross product is a vector perpendicular to that plane and therefore the angle between the cross product vector and either of the original vectors is 90 degrees. If the original two vectors are perpendicular to eachother and one of them is unit length then the resulting vector is equivalent to rotating the non-unit length vector by 90 degrees about the unit vector.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now....@Wolfie Thank u for the information. I will take care in future :)